# Inserting Hyperlinks into the WebGrid

Tags: c#, .net, razor, webmatrix, webgrid

I have searched high and low, and it was only a few weeks ago I saw heaps of sites that had little samples for this, but for the life of me can't find them now!

I have a webgrid, and for certain columns, I need to insert hyperlinks into the rows, like:

```
<a href="someurl.cshtml?something=this&that=something" title="eh?">@rowValue</a>
```

Are there any Docs for this? All I can seem to find on MSDN is very basic stuff, and this doesn't seem to be in there.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
grid.Column(
    format: @<a href="someurl.cshtml?something=this&that=something" title="eh?">@row.Value</a>
)
```

The `format` parameter will accept HTML, so long as you prefix it with the `@` sign and it is self-closing, or wrapped in `<text>` tags. It's a Razor Template, which is described by [Phil Haack here](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/02/27/templated-razor-delegates.aspx) and [Andrew Nurse here](http://vibrantcode.com/blog/2010/8/2/inside-razor-part-3-templates.html).

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can use the format with @Html.ActionLink, e.g.

`grid.Column(
header: "Name", 
canSort: true, 
columnName: "Customer.LastName", 
format: @<text>@Html.ActionLink(linkText: (string)@item.Customer.LastName + ", " + (string)@item.Customer.FirstName, 
actionName: "Details", 
routeValues: new { id = item.Id })
</text>)`

In the code fragment "item" has property "Customer" that has properties LastName and FirstName